Failing to get the data from one screen to another - expo router
Im trying to push data into a modal screen when i press on an image but im failing to get the data neede here is the code :
app/(drawer)/Exercices/index.js:
const Exercice = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.FlatListStyle}
        data={ExercicesDetails}
        numColumns={1}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 50, paddingTop: 20 }}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <ExerciceCard index={index} item={item} />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const ExerciceCard = ({ item, index }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.ImageContainer}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log("Selected Item:", item);
          router.push({
            pathname: "/ExercicesModal/ExerModal",
            state: { exercice: item },
          });
        }}
      >
        <Image
          source={item.image}
          resizeMode="cover"
          style={styles.stretchingImage}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

app/ExercicesModal/ExerModal.js:
const ExerModal = () => {
  **const { exercice } = useRouter();
  const router = useRouter;
  console.log("Exercice:", exercice); // Log msg**
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        source={exercice ? exercice.image : null}
        resizeMode="cover"
        style={styles.stretchingImage}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

log messages :
LOG  Selected Item: {"image": 26, "instruction": "1.Clasp your hands in front of you and lower your head in line with your arms.
2.Press forward and hold for 10 to 30 seconds.", "name": "Forward Stretch"}
LOG  Exercice: undefined
im dont know where my error is .. been stuck here for days , the app work and when i click on the image the modal opens but cant get the data for the specific image clicked on ...
Im new to react native would appreciate it if someone help me .. been stuck here for days
im expecting the log message to be like that :
LOG  Selected Item: {"image": 26, "instruction": "1.Clasp your hands in front of you and lower your head in line with your arms.
2.Press forward and hold for 10 to 30 seconds.", "name": "Forward Stretch"}
LOG  Exercice: {"image": 26, "instruction": "1.Clasp your hands in front of you and lower your head in line with your arms.
2.Press forward and hold for 10 to 30 seconds.", "name": "Forward Stretch"}
